# Lifetime deduction and borrowing in generic functions (required for generic-tests)

Tags: generics, rust, factory, lifetime

Assume a simple trait which allows an object reference to be attached. I used `String` here to make the code a little bit simpler.

```rust
trait Attachable<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn attach(&mut self, value: &'a String);
}
```

A simplistic implementation could look like:

```rust
struct SomeAttachable<'a> {
    id: Option<&'a String>,
}

impl<'a> Attachable<'a> for SomeAttachable<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { id: None }
    }
    fn attach(&mut self, value: &'a String) {
        self.id = Some(value)
    }
}
```

and using it works out of the box.

```rust
let mut object = SomeAttachable::new();
let value = "hello".to_string();
object.attach(&value);
```

But when this is put into a generic function where only the attachable type is provided it breaks.

```rust
fn do_stuff<'a, T: Attachable<'a>>() {
    let mut object = T::new();
    let value: String = "hello".to_string();
    object.attach(&value); // breaks here since value does not live long enough
}
```

I assume that the lifetime is detected when the function `do_stuff` is called and then `value` has a "wrong" lifetime requirement. How can I correct the lifetime issue in the implementation `do_stuff`.

Adjusting the function signature to:

```rust
fn do_stuff_with_argument<'a, T: Attachable<'a>>(value: &'a String) {
    let mut bla = T::new();
    bla.attach(&value);
}
```

would solve the problem since now the lifetime is detected correctly again since it is part of the input reference argument. But this wouldn't be a suitable solution for me. The `do_stuff` function shall handle all the logic inside the function without requiring any function arguments. Only generic arguments are allowed like lifetimes and types.

I assume that I may have to use Higher-Rank Trait Bounds and implement `do_stuff` like:

```rust
fn do_stuff<T>()
where
    T: for<'a> Attachable<'a>,
{
    let mut object = T::new();
    let value: String = "hello".to_string();
    object.attach(&value);
}
```

but this causes rust to complain that the implementation of `Attachable` is not generic enough for `SomeAttachable`.

To provide some context: I require this for unit tests based on the `generic-test` crate where the behavior of a trait is verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `AttachableTag` trait, with a generic associated type that gives you an `Attachable<'a>` for any `'a` (you can also use the same trait and type, but I prefer it this way):

```rust
trait AttachableTag {
    type Attachable<'b>: Attachable<'b>;
}

trait Attachable<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn attach(&mut self, value: &'a String);
}

struct SomeAttachableTag;

impl AttachableTag for SomeAttachableTag {
    type Attachable<'b> = SomeAttachable<'b>;
}

struct SomeAttachable<'a> {
    id: Option<&'a String>,
}

impl<'a> Attachable<'a> for SomeAttachable<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { id: None }
    }
    fn attach(&mut self, value: &'a String) {
        self.id = Some(value)
    }
}

fn do_stuff<T: AttachableTag>() {
    let mut object = T::Attachable::new();
    let value: String = "hello".to_string();
    object.attach(&value);
}

do_stuff::<SomeAttachableTag>();
```

However, this gives an error:

```
error[E0597]: `value` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:32:19
   |
32 |     object.attach(&value);
   |                   ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
33 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `value` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `object` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `<T as AttachableTag>::Attachable<'_>`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

To fix that, move `value`'s declaration before `object`:

```rust
fn do_stuff<T: AttachableTag>() {
    let value: String = "hello".to_string();
    let mut object = T::Attachable::new();
    object.attach(&value);
}
```